# change labels in legend for ggplot2

Tags: r, datetime, plot, ggplot2

I have time series data and I want to plot x vs y and color (gradient) by datetime so I am converting DATETIME to numeric, but the problem is that it takes the numeric value in the legend as well.

```
date         x        y
2012-01-01 14:25:00 461.2339 15.83793
2012-01-01 14:30:00 459.8557 15.80326
```

here is the code

```
ggplot(test1_data,aes(x , y ,colour = as.numeric(date))) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_colour_gradientn(colours=rev(rainbow(6)))
```

Is there a way to edit the legends to show actual datetime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `breaks` and `labels`. Here's an example. You'll need to change the format to suit your actual data.

```
library("ggplot2")
test1_data <- read.csv(text = "date,x,y
               2012-01-01 14:25:00,461.2339,15.83793
               2012-01-01 14:30:00,459.8557,15.80326",
               header = TRUE,
               colClasses = c("POSIXct", rep("numeric", 2)))
date_breaks <- diff(range(test1_data$date)) * 0:4 / 4 +
  min(test1_data$date)
date_labels <- format(date_breaks, "%H:%M:%S")
ggplot(test1_data,aes(x , y ,colour = as.numeric(date))) +
    geom_point() +
    scale_colour_gradientn(colours=rev(rainbow(6)),
                           breaks = as.numeric(date_breaks),
                           labels = date_labels)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add 3 parameters to overwrite the attribute of legends.
1. legend title, 2. breaks, 3.labels

```
scale_colour_gradientn("date", colours=rev(rainbow(6)), 
    breaks = as.numeric(test1_data$date), 
    labels = test1_data$date)
```